# Get a property name from a lambda expression *without* an object instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, lambda, reflection

Asp.net MVC introduced the `EditorFor` method on the Html generic class. It allows you to write code that succinctly identifies a field of the view model. In this case the page this code is from must have a view model of some type that has a `StudentId` property or else this won't work.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StudentId)
```

The signature of the `EditorFor` property is something like this.

```
EditorFor<TModel,TValue>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel,TValue>>)
```

The method is defined on a generic type that knows the type of the `TModel`. So the lambda expression can be as simple as `m => m.StudentId` and we all know that the type of `m` is whatever `TModel` is. In this case it is the page's view model.

I would like to be able to write similar code, without knowing what type the property is defined on. I'd like to be able to write...

```
@Html.EditorFor(M.StudentId) // here M is a type not a lambda parameter
@Html.EditorFor(X.Y) // here X is a type not a lambda parameter
```

I'd like to be able to specify an arbitry type, and an arbitrary parameter, and have the method called with something that identifies both. For example if the method were called with a `PropertyInfo` then I could see both the property and the type it was defined on, both.

Said another way... In the same way that `nameof(X.Y)` gives a string `"Y"` for any arbitrary type `X`, I'd like an expression that gives something like a `PropertyInfo` too. Maybe `property(X.Y)` and you get back the `PropertyInfo` of the property `Y` from the type `X`.

Comment: Sample code `CallMethodWithProperty(x => x.Y);` does not demonstrate any need for an object instance... Can you please clarify what is the exact problem you are facing with that line (also review [MCVE] guidance on posting code - adding extra `var x = new X()` is totally unnecessary... instead showing definition of `CallMethodWithProperty` could improve the question - consider to [edit] it )

Comment: Thanks I updated the question to clarify and demonstrate exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: Still don't get it: `() => X.Y` doesn't make sense *unless* you have an object, either one from the enclosing scope, or passing it through as a parameter `X => X.Y`

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks but that example uses a lambda expression *with* an instance variable, in that case they have `u`. I am interested in it *without* any instance variable.

Comment: @JohnDeHope it is still very unclear what you want to achieve with the code you trying to write... and you have not removed unrelated `var x = new X()` line... Also with you next edit please clarify if the other way to write `Call(x => x.Y)` - `Call(X.Y)` is something you considered. (clearly it can't be what you are looking for as there is no difference between `x => x.Y` and `X.Y`)

Comment: OP, I think you are confused about what lambda expressions actually express. In your first example, the `x` in the lambda expression isn't the instance you created in with the `new` keyword immediately above; it's a declaration of a parameter to the expression, which becomes a *new* local variable within the expression. The instance isn't used.

Comment: @JohnDeHope: not sure what you understand by instance here. There's lambda expression constrained by type T and the u in u => u.Prop is not an instance but a variable that binds to a T so that the lambda is possible. Why would that not fit you? Just because you want another approach?

Comment: @JohnWu Thank you that does help. You're right I wasn't thinking all the way through about where `x` is really defined at. So you are right I was confused about that. I am rewriting the question to make it clear what I am after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a property expression the same way as `EditorFor`. You can do this without an instance.

The one difference is you'll have to specify the type of the expression's parameter to tell the compiler what the object type is. So instead of

```
EditorFor( x => x.Name );    //Specifies a property but not a type
```

...your expression would look like this:

```
EditorFor( (MyType x) => x.Name ); //Specifies property and the type it belongs to
```

You can accomplish this with a short method like this one:

```
static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TIn, TOut>(Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> expression)
{
    var memberExp = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    return memberExp?.Member as PropertyInfo;
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
var p1 = GetPropertyInfo((string s) => s.Length);
Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", p1.DeclaringType.FullName, p1.Name);

var p2 = GetPropertyInfo((DateTime d) => d.Minute);
Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", p2.DeclaringType.FullName, p2.Name);

var p3 = GetPropertyInfo((Stream s) => s.CanSeek);
Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", p3.DeclaringType.FullName, p3.Name);
```

Output:

```
System.String.Length
System.DateTime.Minute
System.IO.Stream.CanSeek
```

Notice that we never needed any instances.

Comment: This is just about exactly what I was looking for. It'd be nice if the syntax could be a bit shorter, such as `property(X.Y)` but what you have here looks shorter than using `nameof`. Thanks!

Comment: From what I learned from @JohnWu I was able to dig around the internet a bit more. I found this helpful. https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1070785/get-property-names-using-lambda-expressions-in-csh